# Update XML using XMLStreamWriter

Tags: java, xml, stax, xmlstreamreader

I have a large XML and I want to update a particular node of the XML (like removing duplicate nodes).

As the XML is huge I considered using the STAX api class - XMLStreamReader. I first read the XML using XMLStreamReader. I stored the read data in user objects and manipulated these user objects to remove duplicates.

Now I want to put this updated user object back into my original XML. What I thought is that I can marshall the user object to a string and place the string at the right position in my input xml. But I am not able to achieve it using the STAX class - XMLStreamWriter

Can this be achieved using XMLStreamWriter? Please suggest.
If no, they please suggest an alternative approach to my problem.

My main concern is memory as I cannot load such huge XMLs into our project server's memory which is shared across multiple processes. Hence I do not want use DOM because this will use lot of memory to load these huge XML.

Comment: Also, please note, in the user objects (beans) I have loaded only those sections which I need to modify. I have not loaded the entire XML into the bean just to save memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to alter a particular value like text content /tag name etc. STAX might help. It would also help in removing few elements using [createFilteredReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbfl.html#bnbgm)

Below code renames `Name` to `AuthorName` and adds a comment

```
public class StAx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
            XMLStreamException {

        String filename = "HelloWorld.xml";

        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
                OutputStream out = System.out;) {
            XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLEventFactory ef = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();

            XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(filename, in);
            XMLEventWriter writer = xof.createXMLEventWriter(out);

            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = (XMLEvent) reader.next();
                if (event.isCharacters()) {
                    String data = event.asCharacters().getData();
                    if (data.contains("Hello")) {
                        String replace = data.replace("Hello", "Oh");
                        event = ef.createCharacters(replace);
                    }
                    writer.add(event);
                } else if (event.isStartElement()) {
                    StartElement s = event.asStartElement();
                    String tagName = s.getName().getLocalPart();
                    if (tagName.equals("Name")) {
                        String newName = "Author" + tagName;
                        event = ef.createStartElement(new QName(newName), null,
                                null);
                        writer.add(event);
                        writer.add(ef.createCharacters("\n          "));
                        event = ef.createComment("auto generated comment");
                        writer.add(event);
                    } else {
                        writer.add(event);
                    }
                } else {
                    writer.add(event);
                }
            }
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BookCatalogue>
    <Book>
        <Title>HelloLord</Title>
        <Name>
            <first>New</first>
            <last>Earth</last>
        </Name>
        <ISBN>12345</ISBN>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Title>HelloWord</Title>
        <Name>
            <first>New</first>
            <last>Moon</last>
        </Name>
        <ISBN>12346</ISBN>
    </Book>
</BookCatalogue>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><BookCatalogue>
    <Book>
        <Title>OhLord</Title>
        <AuthorName>
            <!--auto generated comment-->
            <first>New</first>
            <last>Earth</last>
        </AuthorName>
        <ISBN>12345</ISBN>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Title>OhWord</Title>
        <AuthorName>
            <!--auto generated comment-->
            <first>New</first>
            <last>Moon</last>
        </AuthorName>
        <ISBN>12346</ISBN>
    </Book>
</BookCatalogue>
```

As you can see things gets really complicated when modification is much more than this like swapping two nodes deleting one node based on state of few other node : delete All Books with price more than average price

Best solution in this case is to produce resulting xml using [xslt transformation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html)

Comment: please note that this answer uses a `XMLEventWriter` instead of a `XMLStreamWriter`.

Comment: What about if I want to change an attribute value? e.g. <Book year="2021>...</Book>

Comment: @Davide Call StartElement.getAttributes, create a Stream from the Iterator (search SO), use Stream.map with a lambda that returns the attributes you don't want to alter and returns XMLEventFactory.createAttribute for the attributes you want to modify. Finally call the iterator method on the Stream. Pass these new attributes to XMLEventFactory.createStartElement to create a Book tag with the updated attributes.